# Change Faker Localization in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, faker

In Lumen 5.8, We can make factories in `database/factories`. 
Faker help us to make dummy data and insert them to database. But It's not possbie to change Faker Localization.

```php
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    ];
});
```

According to Faker Documents, we can set a language by using faker factory like this:

```php
$faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
```

So, How can i use Faker Localization inside of Lumen dependency injection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one in you AppServiceProdiver.php file :

```
$this->app->singleton(FakerGenerator::class, function () {
    return FakerFactory::create('fr_FR');
});
```

Works on Laravel, should be the same here